# What is Double.parseDouble(String) and what is the difference between Double.parseDouble(String) and Double.valueOf(double)?

Tags: java, arrays, string, double

I don't know how to convert a `String` to a `double`.  How can I use `Double.parseDouble(String)` and `Double.valueOf(double)`?  I would also like to know the difference between `Double.parseDouble(String)` and `Double.valueOf(double)`.

Comment: you should use Double.parseDouble(String) if you want to change string to double but the difference between Double.parseDouble(String) and Double.valueOf(double) is that the first gets string as an argument and later gets double as an argument

Comment: @Parsa there are two versions of `Double.valueOf()` method. One takes a `double` as an argument, other takes a `String` as an argument.

Comment: in that case there are no differences between these two except the fact that parseDouble returns a new double whereas the other one doesnt

Comment: @Parsa There are more difference, don't ignore the return type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how to convert string to double

```
String str = "0.222";
double dstr = Double.parseDouble(str);
```

> I would also like to know the difference between
>   Double.parseDouble(String) and Double.valueOf(double).

`.parseDouble()` returns a primitive `double` whereas `.valueOf()` returns an instance of `Double` class.

See official doc for [Double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) class for more details.

Comment: thanks for your answer and this is good explanation to me.

Answer (score 2):

The basic difference is that `parseDouble()` returns a `double` which is a primitive data type while `valueOf()` returns an object of `Double` which is a wrapper class.

Comment: thanks for the your answer.